# Excel - copy row which have non-blank cell to another tab

Tags: excel, rows, vba

I need to make this situation happened:
Let's say I have three different tabs, let's call them `Atab`, `Btab` and `Sum.`

In `Atab` and `Btab` I have rows of information. In `column K`, I have a "comment column".

If the comment column in some row is not blank (it has a comment) - I want the whole row to be coppied to `Sum tab.`

So in the `Sum tab` I will see all of the rows of `Atab` and `Btab` with comments `(on K column)`.

Is it possible? :)

Comment: Seems to me an automated solution would have to use VBA to fully satisfy what you want. A quick fix would be just filter the two tables on the comment column, and manually copy and paste into the end sheet.

Comment: `AutoFilter` on that column and then copy it across. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) will get you started

Answer (score 0):

> I want the whole row to be coppied to Sum tab.

I'm assuming you mean “the sum of the Atab and Btab should be placed in Sum tab” and with *tab* you mean a cell. Then the task is easy, use this formula:

```
=IF(K1<>""; SUM(A1:B1); 0)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the asker meant. He wants all rows having a comment in column K to be copied from  `Sheet1` (called Atab) and `Sheet2` (called Btab) to `Sheet3` (called Sum).

Comment: @Physikbuddha Well, we both don't know what the asker means by *tab*. I assumed a cell but a sheet might be equally correct. Thanks for notice, I clarified my answer.